# How to install ember-cli version 1.13.11 without global?

Tags: node.js, npm, ember.js, nodes, ember-cli

I just install nvm software and I will run nvm install 4.0.0. The node will download and npm also download and install it automatically. Next, I will run nvm use 4.0.0 set-up will set it. now I see my node version using `node -v` it shows v4.0.0 all are correct all comments under admin only and I will create one folder and change to that path and I will run `npm install ember-cli@4.0.0` it will install it successfully but after that I use `ember -v` it shows ember is not recognized?

Comment: if you want to use a local installed bin package use `npx` as in `npx ember -v`

Comment: I have a suspicion that you should've restarted your console and then `ember -v` might start to work.